# Removing Embedded object in array in meteor error

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

Ive researched and seen questions in how to remove embedded documents in mongodb/meteor here in stackoverflow and on meteor forums. But I can't figure out why $pull wont work for me.

Been stuck in this problem for days. I have a collection that looks like this.

```
{
  "_id": "N6QAJQpq4p5aYbpev",
  "name": "Test Project",
  "description": "description here",
  "organization": "xPtaobSBQwxCKAJLN",
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "3b7sbW3x487PzzJ6h",
      "role": "manager",
      "dateAdded": "2018-01-24T17:49:50.734Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "n72PveQmdjcsvv5t5",
      "role": "manager",
      "dateAdded": "2018-01-24T17:49:53.545Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "dSqzezqQjrzLeSTEw",
      "role": "manager",
      "dateAdded": "2018-01-24T17:50:11.177Z"
    }
  ]
}`
```

my method in updating the record:

```
removeUserFromProj: (projId, memberId) =>{
  Projects.update({ _id: projId }, {
     $pull: { "members": { id: memberId } }
     // $pull: { "members.id":  memberId  }
  },
     function (error, success) {
        if (error) {
           console.log('error: ', error);
        }
        if (success) {
           console.log('updating user role: ' + success);
        }
     });
```

}

the callback function is giving me a success

[image]

but the collection is not updating.

If i use this syntax `// $pull: { "members.id":  memberId  }` its giving me this error saying:

```
simulating the effect of invoking 'removeUserFromProj' Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty
```

I also tried using $pop instead of $pull. It is removing the last record in my collection.

[image]

I am using meteor SimpleSchema.

Comment: can you share the part of the schema describing the members array so we can try to reproduce ?

Comment: It's seem that you didn't specify the optionnal: true in your schema. i tried the $pull and it's working correctly. The "imulating the effect of invoking 'removeUserFromProj' Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty" error tells you that when you pull the last element your key will disappear from the document witch mean it won't be on the schema anymore

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @Rolljee Thankyou for defining that error to me. I found the problem, I put the answer on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my bug. It seems like the autoValue property in my schema is preventing me to update my

```
OrganizationSchema = new SimpleSchema({
       name: {
          type: String,
          label: "Organization Name"
       },
       createdAt: {
          type: Date,
          autoValue: function(){
             return new Date()
          }  
       },
       createdBy:{
          type: String
       },
       members: {
          type: [Member],
          optional: true
       }
    });
```

changing the autoValue Property to

```
createdAt: {
   type: Date,
   autoValue: function(){
             return new Date()
   }  
}
```

defaultProperty Solved my issue:

```
createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      defaultValue:  new Date()
   },
```